# Etiquetas del head se ubican dentro del body

Tags: php

Hola estoy tratando de subir una pagina hecha en php a un hosting windows pero me encuentro con que al revisar con el inspector de elementos en el navegador todas las etiquetas que deberían estar en el head ahora están el body, y en head aparecen unas etiquetas style y script además aparecen unos caracteres al principio del body, (ademas el .ico no aparece en chrome solo en firefox)  tal como lo muestra la imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código fuente:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
        <title>NixBlue</title>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no shrink-to-fit=no">
            <meta name="description" content="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Commodi facilis ipsam, maxime facere excepturi ipsa minus sint! Repudiandae, saepe, omnis.">
            <link rel='shorcut icon' href='nixblue.ico' type='image/x-icon'>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="views/css/bootstrap.min.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="views/css/estilos.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="views/css/fonts.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="views/css/sweetalert.css">

            <script src="views/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
            <script src="views/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
            <script src="views/js/all.min.js"></script>
            <script src="views/js/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body class="mainBody">
            <header>
                <div class="container">
                <div class="h1Contenedor col-12 d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center p-0">
                    <h1>nix<span>blue</span></h1>
                    <p><a href="index.php?action=Espanol">Español</a>  <span>/</span>  <a href="index.php?action=English">English</a></p>
                </div>
            </header>
            <section class="main" id="main">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row textos">
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <h1 class="text-center" id="welcome">Welcome to lorem ipsum</h1>
                            <h2 class="text-center" id="descripcion">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque et ipsum blandit enim cursus tempor. Quisque non nulla id odio laoreet </h2>
                            <h3 class="text-center" id="comingSoon">We are coming soon</h3>
                            <p class="textoLanzamiento text-center" id="textoLanzamiento">Have a question or need more info?</p>
                            <div class="col-12 d-flex justify-content-center" id="contacto">
                                <button  class="btn contactUs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ModalContact">Contact us</button>
                                <button  class="suscribirse btn m-0" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ModalSuscribe">Suscribe</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>


          <!-- Modal mensaje -->
          <div class="modal" id="ModalContact">
            <div class="modal-dialog modalContenido">
              <div class="modal-content">

                <!-- Modal Header -->
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                </div>

                <!-- Modal body -->
                <div class="modal-body">
                <h3>Send us a message</h3>
                  <form method="post" class="form-row formMensaje" onsubmit="return validarMensajeEn()">
                        <div class="form-group col-12 col-lg-6">
                            <input type="text" autocomplete="off" id="nombresEnglish" name="nombresEnglish" class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-12 col-lg-6">
                            <input type="text" autocomplete="off" id="apellidosEnglish" class="form-control" placeholder="Lastname" name="apellidosEnglish">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-12 col-lg-6">
                            <input type="text" autocomplete="off" id="nombreEmpresaEnglish" name="nombreEmpresaEnglish" class="form-control" placeholder="Company name">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-12 col-lg-6">
                            <input type="text" autocomplete="off" id="paisEnglish" name="paisEnglish" class="form-control" placeholder="Country">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-12">
                            <input type="email" autocomplete="off" id="emailEnglish" name="emailEnglish" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-12">
                            <textarea id="mensajeEnglish" name="mensajeEnglish" class="form-control "placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-12 d-flex justify-content-end">
                            <input class="btn btnEnviarMensaje" type="submit" value="Send">
                        </div>
                    </form>
                    <?php 
                        $mensajeEnviado = new MensajesControllerEnglish();
                        $mensajeEnviado -> registroMensajesController();

                        ?>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>


         <!-- modal suscribe-->

         <div class="modal ModalSuscribe" id="ModalSuscribe">
            <div class="modal-dialog modalSuscribirse">
              <div class="modal-content">

                <!-- Modal Header -->
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                </div>

                <!-- Modal body -->
                <div class="modal-body">
                <h3>Suscribe to our newsletter</h3>
                  <form method="post" autocomplete="off"  class="form-inline suscribirse position-relative" onsubmit="return validarsuscriptorMensajeEnglish()">
                        <div class="input-group w-100">
                            <input type="text" name="suscriptorEnglish" class=" form-control" id="suscriptorEnglish" placeholder="Email address">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btnNotify">Notify me</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                    <?php
                        $suscriptorEnviado = new  MensajesControllerEnglish();
                        $suscriptorEnviado -> registroSuscriptorFormController();
                    ?>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>


            <footer class="footer" id="footer">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="social col-12 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
                            <a href="https://wa.me/573002496542" target="_blank"><span class="whatsapp"><i class="fab fa-whatsapp"></i></span></a>
                            <a href="https://m.me/facebook" target="_blank"><span class="facebook"><i class="fab fa-facebook-messenger"></i></span></a>
                        </div>
                        <p class="text-center">© Myrtus group S.A.S 2019 </p>
                        <p class="text-center">Bogotá Colombia South America</p>
                        <a href="index.php?action=privacyPolitics" class="text-center politics">Privacy politics</a>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </footer>
            <script src="views/js/validarMensaje.js"></script>
            <script src="views/js/script.js"></script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Cual seria el problema y como se podria solucionar

Gracias por su ayuda

Comment: Copié tu código e hice una prueba en local y todo está donde debe estar dentro del inspector de código. El archivo `nixblue.ico` debe estar en el mismo directorio de tu código y debes corregir, como te sugiere @tiberius en su respuesta, `rel='shortcut icon'` para que funcione.

Comment: Si en el local funciona de maravilla el problema es al. Subirlo a un servidor Windows leí que era algo relacionado con el bom de la conexión y que por esto se podrían presentar comportamientos extraños como la inserción de espacios en blanco o caracteres cosa que me pasa tal como lo muestra la imagen, pero no he podido  encontrar más info al respecto  al menos no soluciones claras

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel='shortcut icon' href='nixblue.ico' type='image/x-icon'>
</head>

<body class="mainBody">
  <header>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="h1Contenedor col-12 d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center p-0">
        <h1>nix<span>blue</span></h1>
        <p><a href="index.php?action=Espanol">Español</a> <span>/</span> <a href="index.php?action=English">English</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>

</html>
```

El content del viewport tiene que ir separado por comas,tienes que cerrar el `<div class="container">` y el icono falla porque es `rel='shortcut icon'`, te faltaba una t.

Comment: hola corregí los errores y sin embargo sigue pasando lo mismo, el <!DOCTYPE html> parece que el navegador no lo reconoce y siguen apareciendo unas etiquetas style y script en el head y el navegador sigue metiendoe l contenido de la la etiqueta head en el body